# Mincha before early wedding

Tags: wedding, mincha-afternoon-prayer, viduy-confession

If a couple is getting married early in the day (before mincha), when do they add the viduy from Yom Kippur to mincha? Do they do it the day before, the day of (after the wedding), or not at all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Mishna Berura 573:8](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49628&st=&pgnum=93) mentions that a Chasan should say Viduy on the day of the wedding. There is no mention that it has to be at Mincha. Most likely the Minhag of saying it at Mincha was done practically as most weddings are after the time of Mincha. However it can be done anytime in the day.

http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/475826/jewish/Day-of-the-Wedding.htm

> If the chupah will be held in the morning, the viduy can be recited
>   after the morning prayer amidah

Comment: I certainly said my vidui at Shacharit.

Comment: The Pitchei Teshuva EH 61:9 does mention to do it st mincha